# SSRS in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sql-server, reporting-services

If I do not choose `Reporting Services SharePoint Integrated Mode` while installing SQL Server and also I didn't installed `Reporting services Add-in for SharePoint` and in future I need to have SSRS in my SharePoint 2013 Farm then how would I be able to get SSRS working in SharePoint 2013? Is there a fix for it or do I need to reinstall SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

You have to run the setup not by removing the existing sql just to add additional features to existing installed sql

see the below post what features need to select to install SharePoint Reporting Services.
https://whitepages.unlimitedviz.com/2012/07/setting-up-reporting-services-2012-with-sharepoint-2013/

You also see this port configure Reporting Services on SharePoint.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/biblog/2012/12/04/installing-and-configuring-sql-reporting-services-on-sharepoint-2013/

Comment: Agree with adding features like "Reporting Services-SharePoint" and "Reporting Services Add-in for SharePoint Products" by re-running the setup but what about installing SQL in "Reporting Services SharePoint Integrated Mode"? Will I get this changed from Native to Integrated Mode by re-running the setup?

Comment: The SSRS database cannot be converted between modes. In addition, the SSRS instance must be installed on a SharePoint server joined to the farm.

Comment: It won' change on the SQL default instance(MSSQL). You have to create a separate instance to host the reporting services.